# SQL JOIN: Just not able to understand them

Tags: mysql, join

Now, I know know this question related to `JOIN` have been asked many times. I went through many of them. But it still isn't clear to me. I read these aricles too: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins#_comments and http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html but no, it still didn't help.

I do understand the Vein diagrams mathematically but not able to grab basic concept behind `JOIN`.

Suppose I have two tables.

tbl_bookdescription:

```
| BOOKID |    BOOKNAME | BOOKREVIEW | AUTHORID |
------------------------------------------------
|      1 |  SQL Basics |       Cool |        1 |
|      2 |  PHP Basics |       Good |        2 |
|      3 | AJAX Basics |     Superb |        2 |
|      4 | HTML Basics |  Very Good |        3 |
```

`tbl_authordescription`

```
| AUTHORID | AUTHORNAME |
-------------------------
|        1 |        Tom |
|        2 |      Jerry |
|        3 |       Phil |
```

I want to script a search engine for my website

So, when the user enters `Tom` as `$searchTerm`, I want the program to return the name of the book which is written by `Tom`. And at the same time, the user can also enter `Good`. This time the query should again return the name of the book. So, I thought to do something like this

```
SELECT bookname FROM tbl_bookdescription MATCH(bookReview) AGAINST('$searchTerm')`
```

and then `UNION` this table with `SOMETHING` (something which matches authorName against $searchterm).

Now, two questions:

1. Is this query right? Will it give me the desired results?
2. WHat should I write in the code in place of `SOMETHING`. I think I will have to `JOIN` both the tables(not sure). And don't know how should I join.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search using only one search term then your query might look like

```
SELECT b.*, a.*
  FROM tbl_bookdescription b JOIN tbl_authordescription a
    ON b.authorID = a.authorID
 WHERE b.bookName   LIKE '%searchterm%'
    OR b.bookReview LIKE '%searchterm%'
    OR a.authorName LIKE '%searchterm%'
```

If you replace `searchterm` with 'Tom' you'll get

```
| BOOKID |   BOOKNAME | BOOKREVIEW | AUTHORID | AUTHORNAME |
------------------------------------------------------------
|      1 | SQL Basics |       Cool |        1 |        Tom |
```

Now, if it's 'Good' then

```
| BOOKID |    BOOKNAME | BOOKREVIEW | AUTHORID | AUTHORNAME |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|      2 |  PHP Basics |       Good |        2 |      Jerry |
|      4 | HTML Basics |  Very Good |        3 |       Phil |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83b6dc/3)** demo

Comment: I didnt know there is something calles SQLFiddle too :)

Comment: YOU  ARE simply using `JOIN` here. which join is it? `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: what if I have another table.. Can I also join it this way?

Comment: @NavneetSaini If you use just `JOIN` it implies that it's `INNER JOIN`. If you want to use one of the outer joins you need to explicitly say `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `FULL` (although MySql has no implementation for `FULL` join).

Comment: Ok, what if I want to join another table.. Can I do it the same way?

Comment: @NavneetSaini Sure, you just need to choose join type and join conditions right.

Comment: @NavneetSaini You are more than welcome! Good luck learning and applying SQL :)

Comment: I still ain't clear with this thing. What does the query written above do? It first assigns alias to  both the tables. Okay, that's fine. But I want to select the things from the table `tbl_bookdescription` only. then, why do we write `SELECT a.*, b.*`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31722/discussion-between-navneet-saini-and-peterm)

Comment: @NavneetSaini If you want only columns from tbl_bookdescription, then ditch `a.*` from `SELECT` clause. You've put it there so that you can see authors names.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
    a.* 
FROM 
    tbl_bookdescription a
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_authordescription b
ON 
    a.authorid = b.authorid 
WHERE 
    b.authorname=''
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is `a` and what's `b` here?

Comment: Then answer one more question. Don't we use `AS` we we want to give alias to something?

Comment: Both the options are allowed, you can also directly give alias without using as

Comment: Cn I also join the third table this way?