# how to get mysql values based on left join condition

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join, having-clause

job table

```
1.id
2.status = 'active'
3.name
```

repair table

```
1.repair id
2.job_id
3.process = 'yes|no'
4.status  = '1|2'
```

job table

```
id   name  status
1    test  active
2    check active
```

repair table

```
repair_id     job_id  process  status
1                1      no        2
2                1      no        1
3                1      yes       2
4                2      no        1
5                2      no        2
```

here i need to show data which ( process != 'yes' and repair_status != 2 ) group by job_id

i need result after query

```
---------------------------------------------
job_id    name( job.name ) status( job.status )
------------------------------------------------
2            check           active
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: where is your query which you tried...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL JOIN: Just not able to understand them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078952/sql-join-just-not-able-to-understand-them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the results that you specify, you mean that `process` is not `yes` for *any* row for the `job_id`.  And then that at least one row has a `status` <> 2.  That would be:

```
select j.job_id, j.name, j.status
from repair r join
     job j
     on r.job_id = r.id
group by j.job_id, j.name, j.status
having max(process) = 'no' and
       min(repair_status) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want jobs for which no repair exists with `process = 'yes'` and `status = 2`, you can use `not exists`:

```
select j.*
from jobs j
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from repair r 
    where r.job_id = j.id and r.process = 'yes' and r.status = 2
)
```